# Check if every character in a string is available in an array c++

Tags: arrays, string, character, contains

I have tried for several hours, but I cannot find a good way in doing so, here is what I want to do.

```
string word = "hello";
string word2 = "hey";
string letters[4] = {"h", "e", "l", "o"};
```

I want it to either return a boolean of true or false if every character in the string "word" is contained in the array "letters" (in this case true) and the string "word2" as false. Any ideas or suggestions? I am new to c++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An efficient solution is to create a boolean array of length 256(Number of possible characters) and initialize it to 0.This array will tell if a certain character is present in your letter string or not.

After that, we can iterate over your string 'word' to check if the character is present in the 'letter' string.
Check this function:

```
bool isContained(string word,string letters){
bool letts[256]={0};
for(int i=0;i<letters.size();i++){
    letts[letters[i]=1;
}
for(int i=0;i<word.size();i++){
    if(!letts[word[i]]){
        return false;
    }
  }
return true;
}
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<ctype.h>

const int MAX = 20

bool check_availability(char word, char letters){
  length_of_letters = sizeof(letters) / sizeof(letters[0])

  for (int i = 0 ; i < length_of_letters ; i++){
    if (letters[i] < word[i] < letters[length_of_letters]) {
      return true
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  clrscr();
  char word[MAX], letters[MAX];
  int lenght;

  cout<<"Please enter a word: ";
  getc(word)

  cout<<"Please enter the length of the array of letters you would be entering: ";
  cin>>length
  for (int i = 0 ; i < length ; i++){
      cin>>letters[i]
  }

  for (int i = 0 ; i < lenght ; i++) {
    res = check_availability(word, letters[i])
    assert(res == true)   //The code will give an assertion error when condition is not satisfied
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-whether-an-array-is-subset-of-another-array-set-1/

Answer (score 0):

You can access each character in string objects by using the [] operator, just as accessing c-strings. Or "at" method of string objects.

So you can have nested for loop, one for word's length and the other for letter's length.

```
bool f(string word, string* letters, int letters_length) {
    for (int i = 0; i < word.size(); i++) {
        bool flag = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < letters_length; j++) {
            if (word[i] == letters[j][0]) { // compare each word's character and each letters's character
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!flag) { // if the word's character couldn't be found in letters, return false
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true; // this can be reached only if all the comparison are passed
}
```

I think this should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool checkLettersIncluded(std::string word, std::string letters)
{
  int includedLetter = 0;
  for(const char c:word)
  {
    for(const char d:letters)
    {
      if(c==d)
      {
        includedLetter++;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return includedLetter == word.length();
}


int main() {
  std::string word = "hello";
  std::string word2 = "hey";
  std::string letters = "helo";
  if(checkLettersIncluded(word2, letters))
  {
    std::cout << "All characters available";
  }  
}
```